# Find an available time frame in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find if a time frame is availability from UNIX start to UNIX end. I have data like:

```
id start      end
1  1309383000 1309390200
2  1305115200 1305129600
3  1305374400 1305403200
```

I am trying to run a query where I have a given start and end, and checking to see if this slow is taken. However, a `start` can start when another entry ends. I have tried a lot of different ways, cannot get it to work right. Any help is appreciated.

I am using PHP to call the query. However, I would like to do it in pure MySQL if possible.

Comment: Basically are you looking for find overlapping time? Look at BETWEEN / NOT BETWEEN sql operator

Comment: I did a lot of tests with those and I got really close but it was never working right.

Comment: try to post your "closer" query

Comment: What do you mean? I am not running another query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  if(max(end) >= $end, max(end), $end) - 
        if(min(start) <= $start, min(start), $start) - 
        if(sum(end - start) is null, 0, sum(end - start))  as FreeTime
where end > $start and start < $end
```

Comment: It kinda works but I get a lot of weird numbers and I am not so sure what to do with them. Sometimes its a bunch of 0's, sometimes its just a 0 and that 0 means its taken but the bunch of 0's means its not. Sometimes I get nothing which means its not taken. Any idea?

Comment: it should have one row as anwser, do you obtain more? see my last correction.  null or cero mings "no free time" other numbers are the free seconds in the time frame. post your tests (and dataset)

Comment: Here is my attempted method using your query before any of those changes you just made. http://pastebin.com/iNJ3VxLp Basically I am just checking for availability between a timespan but one can start when another timespan ends.

Comment: this is necesary for my code to work proplely: _but one can start when another timespan ends_

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM timeslots
WHERE ($your_start NOT BETWEEEN start AND end) AND
   ($your_end NOT BETWEEN start and end)
```

If that returns a count > 0, then the requested time slot is at least partially taken.

Comment: This seemed to always return something

Comment: Yes, it will, because you're doing a count. It'll always return a number. You have to retrieve that number. If it's 0, then the time slot is available. Otherwise it's in use.  mmm.... that or I'm brain dead today. Think I got my logic backwards. Try doing just 'between', not 'not between'. That'll make 0 = available, non-0 = not available.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do it. I placed a 2 hour slot 1 hour before one starts and it returns 0. Then I placed it when one ends and it returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

add 1 unit to startTime and subtract 1 unit from endTime, then use between clause for retrieving rows.