# PHP/MySQL - Calender/Setting appointments question

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, select

I have to columns, both datetimes. One's for the time the appointment starts and the other is for when the appointment ends.

I need a mysql query that'll basically return available time during the day so I can set appointments without them overlapping.

So if I'm open on Monday from 1pm to 6pm and have an appointment from 2pm to 3pm it'll return two results:

DATE 13:00:00 - DATE 14:00:00 and DATE 15:00:00 - DATE 18:00:00

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439803/php-date-booking-and-review-methods isn't specifically addressing your answer, but you should look to see how PHP Calendar for Room Booking functions...

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523658/find-an-available-time-frame-in-mysql) is more along the lines of what you're looking for, I think.

Comment: @sdolgy a friend of mine actually recommended i do something like that.. create a 5 minute time slot per id and for eg; assign 6 to a 30 minute appointment. im actually considering something like that as well, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to always have 2 datetimes, one being the start time, one being the end time. That would be the 'cleaner' way in my opinion.

The way to get the open appointments is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM appointments
WHERE end_time = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" (or > in stead of = for all appointments)
```

Or if you leave it empty something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM appointments
WHERE end_time IS NULL (or IS NOT NULL for all appointments)
```

Comment: that's what i was thinking and i guess i'd need some type of query where i could do.. select * from app where date falls on certain days but NOT IN the range of appointments already set, if that's possible.

Comment: I suppose you want all appoinments for a given day then?

Comment: That would mean the second column would be empty (or default value = 01-01-1970 00:00 i beleve).

Comment: This would also require that there be an entry in the database for every time slot (including open slots), not just for booked appointments.

Comment: no, the idea is not to fill a table with available slots, but to query for scheduled days and with logic find out what slots are available

Comment: in that case there is no problem i suppose.. just `SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE begin_time > "some date" AND end_time < "some date"` to get all appointments in the time you need and you can do your logic.